# how to insert to dictionary key null?

Tags: c#

I have a list where I want to group it by field, but the field can be nullable int?
`asd.Value?.GroupBy(x => x.ParentId == null ? 0 : x.ParentId).ToDictionary(gg => gg.Key, gg => gg.ToList());` 
GEtting an error: The type 'int?' cannot be used as type parameter 'TKey' in the generic type or method 'Enumerable.ToDictionary(IEnumerable, Func, Func)'. Nullability of type argument 'int?' doesn't match 'notnull' constraint.

How can I then group the data separately in Dictionary?

Comment: @dbc `Dictionary` calls neither of those methods, it uses a comparer, and the comparer can do *whatever it wants*, including supporting null values (most comparers, including the default comparer, handle null values just fine).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It looks like you don't actually *need* a `Dictionary<,>` that uses nullable keys, because you're already replacing any `null` values with `0` here:

```
.GroupBy(x => x.ParentId == null ? 0 : x.ParentId)
```

But this still results in a *type* of `int?` (or `Nullable<int>`), even if it replaces all `null` values with `0`.  And that type is being used as the key here:

```
.ToDictionary(gg => gg.Key, gg => gg.ToList())
```

And even though none of the values *are* `null`, because the type *allows* `null` the compiler will still indicate this.

However, continuing your goal of replacing all `null` values with `0` anyway, instead of using `x.ParentId`, you can use the `.Value` property on the `Nullable<>` type:

```
.GroupBy(x => x.ParentId.HasValue ? x.ParentId.Value : 0)
```

So it still replaces the `null` values, but the resulting type of the ternary expression is now `int` because both expressions after the `?` are an `int`.

---

Alternatively, if you're confident that previous parts of the expression tree did successfully remove all `null` values, you can also use the `.Value` here instead:

```
.ToDictionary(gg => gg.Key.Value, gg => gg.ToList())
```

Though it's up to you to ensure that there are no `null` values, as this would fail at runtime if there are.